# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple' while using summary() for pytorch model

Tags: pytorch, typeerror

As I am designing a multimodal architecture, with a 3dcnn and 2dcnn, so i want to view the model architecture like in Keras. The input size are as in the picture, and i kept getting this error when i try to print the structure, but no issue while running it for training and model evaluation.
[image]

```
class CombineModel(nn.Module): #A multimodal network(3D and 2D CNN), with multioutputs (2 outputs)
  def __init__(self, num_classes):
    super(CombineModel, self).__init__()
    self.CNN3D = CNN3DModel() #output size is (512,1)
    self.Unet = UNet11() #output size is (512,1)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 1)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten() 
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax()

  def forward(self,x1,x2):
    out1 = self.CNN3D(x1)
    out2 = self.Unet(x2)
    outa = torch.cat((out1, out2), dim=1)
    outa = self.fc1(outa)
    outa = self.relu(outa)
    outa = self.softmax(self.fc2(outa))
    outb = self.fc3(self.relu(out2))

    return outa, outb
```

Comment: please add a minimal working code snippet that exhibits your problem.

Comment: @Shir hi there, the question is updated

Comment: Sorry, this is not a working example (please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be preferable that you copy paste the whole stacktrace in the question instead of putting an image/screenshot of it